# PAT test void on dismantling the plug?

Tags: plug

Apologies if this is the wrong place.

In the UK there is a PAT test for electrical appliances to ensure it's safe to use and meets standards, and is usually a requirement from insurers.

I had to dismantle a plug today to pull it through a small gap. My manager thinks that it needs an entirely new PAT test now and I've never heard of anything like that. I haven't removed or added anything, it's the same plug just taken apart and put back together again. I didn't even disconnect the terminals.

Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: PAT testing is more than an insurance requirement, it is a legal requirement.

Comment: Is it still normal (or at least not uncommon) to assemble your own plugs in the UK? That would be a big problem if everyone had to get their appliances re-tested after assembling the plug.

Comment: It's not normal by any means, most appliances come with moulded plugs that you can't disassemble anymore. It just happened that the one that I was trying to pull through had the old style that you can dismantle, and I love all the safety features of the UK plug so I definitely put it back together the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

*Technically,* you don't have to do any PAT testing at all, but of course, your insurer requires it.

[PAT FAQ](https://www.hse.gov.uk/electricity/faq-portable-appliance-testing.htm)

I would say that if you are considered a competent person to do the work you just did, you would probably be fine. If the device previously passed PAT testing, and you haven't damaged the plug or wiring in any way I'd be comfortable in saying it was still safe.

If your manager want's to pay for additional testing thats their problem though.